# Error new version PUGX Multi User Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pugxmultiuserbundle

I have a new error in my Symfony 3 Project when I update my composer.

[Error Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhyYZ.png)

[Error Symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqJYa.png)

I had no errors since few months and I didn't touch the code since.

I saw that the error is from a new version of PUGX, (released the 12/10/2016). So my project don't work anymore.

I would like to know if I can go back to a stable release using Composer or if there is an issue with the PUGX Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to require the specific commit in your `composer.json`, it will look like this:

```
"bundle": dev-master#commitHash
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nickolaus for your answer, I modify my composer.json with your code and a stable commit but I get a "problem" when I execute my code :

```
Problem 1 
    -The requested package pugx/multi-user-bundle dev-master#3b4abe5cf7626add185a66c22452cb74ec2b1921 exists as pugx/multi-user-bundle[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev, 2.0.x-dev, dev-master, 3.0.x-dev, v1.4.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```